# Javascript, Objects, Functions and Case statement problems

Tags: javascript, function, object, switch-statement

Hello I'm currently learning javascript in my free time using the www.codeacademy.com website.

One example asks me to create an object, then call a function to search for a name from those objects.  Which ever object has the name, then all the properties should be displayed to screen.  I can do this with an if else statement easy.  Whats confusing me is i cant get it to work with a case statement.  Instead of choosing the correct case, it 'always' picks the first case. The code i have is as below.  it includes some debugging lines to try and help me understand why its not behaving how i think it should:

```
var movie = {};

movie.toyStory2 = {
     name: "Toy Story 2",
     review: "Great story. Mean prospector."
};

movie.findingNemo = {
     name: "Finding Nemo",
     review: "Cool animation, and funny turtles."
};

movie.theLionKing = {
     name: "The Lion King",
     review: "Great songs."
};

var list = function(obj) {
     for (var prop in obj) {
          console.log(1,prop);
     }
};

var getReview = function (name) {
     for (var name in movie) {
          console.log(2, name);  // debug line
          console.log(3, movie); // debug line

          switch (movie) { // debug line  i have used different switches to no avail
                          // movie  prop  name  amongst others, though logically
                          // i think this should work
               case "Toy Story 2":
                    console.log(4, movie[name].review); // debug line
                    return movie[name].review;
                    break;
               case "Finding Nemo":
                    console.log(5, movie[name].review); // debug line
                    return movie[name].review;
                    break;
               case "The Lion King":
                    console.log(666, movie[name].review); // debug line
                    return movie[name].review;
                    break;
               default:
                    console.log(7, movie[name].review); // debug line
                    return ("I don't know!");
                    break;
          }
    }
};

list(movie);
//getReview("Toy Story 2"); // debug line
//getReview("Finding Nemo"); // debug line
getReview("The Lion King");
```

Objects are the hardest part to understand in programming for me, Any help would be greatly appreciated, please be gently :D

I never expected any replies instantly, thanks for your advice.  I've taken it on board and cleaned up my post. Apologies

Comment: `"THE CODE WOULD HAVE BEEN HERE, RATHER THAN SPENDING TIME FORMATTING IT FOR FORUM VIEW I'VE ATTACHED A JPEG

OF IT FOR EASIER READABILITY."` -- and if we want to run it ourselves -- we have to type it in ourselves?

Comment: Translated: yes, spend the time to make it easy for folks to help you.

Comment: People still mistake JavaScript with Java?

Comment: Please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: This isn't even Java, please

Comment: Wow this question is going to have even less votes than [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519990/why-does-i-j-k-j-i-kk-i-j-11)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `switch` statement doesn't look for the object whose name matches the `name` argument. It just goes through each `case` statement until it finds one that matches the name of the current property in the `for` loop. Since the first property in the object has `name = "Toy Story 2"`, the first `case` statement matches. So it executes the `console.log()` statement and then returns from the function.

There's no reason to use a `switch` statement for this. It should be:

```
for (var prop in movie) {
    if (movie[prop].name == name) {
        console.log(5, movie[prop].name);
        return movie[prop].review;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou Barmar, i used that.  The tutorial was adamant i used a switch statement though.  I worked it out in the end by simply removing the for loop.  Though the tutorial would accept it as correct even then.  I appreciate your help.